# How to avoid memory leaks when MATLAB function inside parfor generates warning?

Tags: matlab, memory-leaks, parfor

I use matlab R2015b for Win Server 2012 OS with local parpool. I have memory leaks on local workers when function inside parfor-loop generate warning. Also memory is not released after parfor-loop ends. Example:

```
x = rand(78, 1);
for j = 1:100
    parfor i = 1:1000
        [~, z] = kpsstest(x);
    end
end
```

function kpsstest generates warning:

Warning: Test statistic #1 below tabulated critical values:
maximum p-value = 0.100 reported. 
 In kpsstest>getStat (line 632)
 In kpsstest (line 291)

Memory leaks on workers even when i use constructions:

```
   warning('off', 'econ:kpsstest:StatTooSmall');
   pctRunOnAll warning('off', 'econ:kpsstest:StatTooSmall')
```

Memory on start workers:
[image]

Memory on after executing code:
[image]

How to avoid memory leaks when function inside parfor generates warning?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is the subject of this  [bug report](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1372271). If you are able to upgrade to R2017a, that's the simplest workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably this is not the cleanest way, but you can shutdown the parallel pool, see [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/delete_pool.html)

Comment: It is clear that restarting parpool return initial memory consumption. In that example memory leaks on ~60 MB, but when i need long-time processing on local cluster with many functions that generate warnings, memory leak can reach hundreds of MB and even a unit of GB. I think this is not normal behavior of MATLAB.

Comment: @JonasVilks I totally agree. This is probably the wrong forum for such a question. Consider asking [here](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/). And if you find an answer, please post it here (and link me, so that I get a notice to have a look at this page)